# Fourier transform of exponentially decaying sinusoid

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> Calculate $$f(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-iwx} {\rm d} x$$ where $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x} \sin(x), & x \geq 0 \\ 0, & x < 0\end{cases}$$

---

My solution was, of course, to compute the integral, and it's easy to do so but then I am stuck with the $\sin(\infty)$. So I thought of another way by replacing $$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$ but I couldn't continue. Can someone please give me any hints?

Comment: Do you know that $e^{-x} \sin(x)$ tends to zero as x tends to infinity, due to the sine being bounded?

Comment: oh my god , I just focused on the sin and forgot about the exponent

Comment: What did you get when you computed the (indefinite) integral?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, as the exponentials are multplied, take the exponentials together
$$
\big ( \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \big ) e^{-x}e^{-iwx} = \frac{1}{2i} \big(e^{x(i-1-iw)}-e^{-x(i+iw+1)} \big ).
$$
Hence, you get for the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2i} \big(e^{x(i-1-iw)}-e^{-x(i+iw+1)} \big ) dx
$$
From this you be able to compute the integral.

Comment: thank you so much,
my bad didn't pay attention to the exponent I apologize